# How to check if every value of an html element is the same in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html looks like

```
<body>
  <span></span> (a random number of spans fit in here)
</body>
```

They all have values that change in less than a second. I'm looking for a way to see if there is one span check if it equals 9 (the text value), if there are 2 check if they both equal 9, if there are 15 check if they all equal 9. I hope you get the point

Comment: *"span check if it equals 9"* you mean span text content?

Comment: _"I hope you get the point"_ Nope. Could you elaborate and show us what you've tried?

Comment: Rather than worry about "are they all 9", why not flip it around? "Are any of them not 9?" is a much easier question to answer.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: how is the solution any different?

Comment: @im1dermike "Are they all 9?" requires scanning every single one to check them. "Are any of them not 9?" lets you stop as soon as you find one that isn't ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Of course, but does filtering constitute "scanning"?

Comment: Basically, the jQuery answer below is extremely bloated and inefficient. An efficient solution would be something like `![].some.call(document.getElementsByTagName('span'), function(s) {return s.textContent != 9;});`

Answer (score 5):

Suppose, you check that all your `spans` have value `42`:

```
if ( $( 'span' ).length === $( 'span' ).filter(function(i, el) { return $(el).text() == '42'; }).length )
```

Here:

```
// number of all spans    
$( 'span' ).length 
// number of spans that have text 42
$( 'span' ).filter(function(i, el) { return $(el).text == '42'; }).length -
```

Or as @Niet the Dark Absol suggested you can check if there any `spans` that don't contain `42`

```
if ( 0 < $( 'span' ).filter(function(i, el) { return $(el).text() != '42'; }).length )
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$(el).text == '42'`?

Comment: Okay) Let is be `42`)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/67xmzdxe/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using ECMAScript5 [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var isEvery = $('span').toArray().every(function(span) {
    return $(span).text().trim() === "9";
});
```

or reverse check [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var isEvery = !$('span').toArray().some(function(span) {
    return $(span).text().trim() !== "9";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9gjw453t/9/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var total = 0;      
    $('span').each(function(){   
       total += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    if(total == 9){
          alert('Total = 9');
     }else{
           alert('Total != 9   total ='+total);
     }
});
```